# Which is the best protocal to use in peer to peer network

Tags: network-programming, p2p

I am working on the project that is asking me to use peer to peer network because this project will be applied in the environment that don't have a server. So I need help on which protocal and C/C++ API I can use to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform peer-to-peer you have to handle [NATs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which means you must perform a [NAT Transversal (NAT Punch)](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/). This is typically done using UDP and STUN. From the second link:

> Here’s a parting “TL;DR” recap: For robust NAT traversal, you need the
> following ingredients:
>
> A UDP-based protocol to augment
>
> Direct access to a socket in your program
>
> A communication side channel with your peers
>
> A couple of STUN servers

Even then you are not guaranteed success. It is a very complicated subject so i recommend reading the entire NAT Transversal article.